# Create unique column in data frame

Tags: r

I have the data frame where the combination of three integer columns is unique.

Something like:

```
     p1_b p2_b p3_b b1 f1 b2 f2 b3  f3 
1       0    0    0  0 40  0 20  0 160 
2       0    0    1  0 40  0 20  4 152
```

Combination of columns (p1_b + p2_b + p3_b) is unique.  I need to create new integer unique column so it preserve the order of (p1_b + p2_b + p3_b) columns.

Something like:

```
> d <- transform(data, id = p1_b * 10000 + p2_b * 100 + p3_b)
```

but more R-specific.

**Update:**

To make my question more clear I give one example:

```
paste0( p1_b, p2_b, p3_b)
```

is not perfect solution as two rows with values (0 1 0) and (0 0 10) gives the same number 10.

Comment: What do you mean more R specific?

Comment: Well, I don't like my solution as it have a magic constants (10 000 and 100).  If p3_b will be bigger than 100 my solution will be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this..

```
transform(data, id = paste0( p1_b, p2_b, p3_b) )


#  p1_b p2_b p3_b b1 f1 b2 f2 b3  f3  id
#1    0    0    0  0 40  0 20  0 160 000
#2    0    0    1  0 40  0 20  4 152 001
```

---

EDIT

---

following your edit if you need an unique integer, then in 3 lines

```
data <- transform(data, ref = paste( p1_b, p2_b, p3_b, sep = ".") )
refDF <- data.frame(ref = unique(data$ref), id = 1:length(unique(data$ref)) )
merge(data, refDF, by = "ref" , all = TRUE)[-1]

#     p1_b p2_b p3_b b1 f1 b2 f2 b3  f3 id
#1    0    0    0  0 40  0 20  0 160  1
#2    0    0    1  0 40  0 20  4 152  2

# id is an integer running 1:n unique p1_b p2_b p3_b comninations
```

or in one line:

```
transform(data, id = as.integer(as.factor(paste( p1_b, p2_b, p3_b, sep = "."))))
```

Comment: First of all I need integer column (sorry, I did'n say it) This solution doesn't preserve the order and uniques.  For example values (0 1 0) and (0 0 10) give (010 and 0010) or 10 as integer.